# Mounting shared folder from local NAS device

Tags: mount, nfs, nas

I'm trying to mount a folder from local NAS device. The model is Zyxel NAS 326.

[image: NAS NFS screen]

On the Ubuntu 18.04 client, I try to run these commands:

```bsh
# does nothing
sudo mount -v -o vers=3.0 -t nfs 192.168.1.33:/i-data/5519db32/nfs/Hiddenslate1 /media/NAS/volume1/
### outputs
mount.nfs: timeout set for Fri Sep  3 16:31:59 2021
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=3.0,addr=192.168.1.33'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.33 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.33 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 38280

# gives permission denied error
sudo mount -v -o vers=3.0 -t nfs 192.168.1.33:/Volume1/i-data/5519db32/nfs/Hiddenslate1 /media/NAS/volume1/

# does nothing
sudo mount -v -o vers=4.0 -t nfs 192.168.1.33:/Hiddenslate1 /media/NAS/volume1/
### outputs
mount.nfs: timeout set for Fri Sep  3 16:32:31 2021
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.0,addr=192.168.1.33,clientaddr=192.168.1.66'

# gives no such file or dir error
sudo mount -v -o vers=4.0 -t nfs 192.168.1.33:/Volume1/Hiddenslate1 /media/NAS/volume1/
```

I understand the second and fourth errors but first or third one should work. I can't see anything in the `/media/NAS/volume1`. What sould I do check?

The output of `rpcinfo 192.168.1.33 | egrep "service|nfs"`

```bsh
   program version netid     address                service    owner
    100003    3    tcp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        superuser
    100003    4    tcp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        superuser
    100003    3    udp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        superuser
    100003    4    udp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        superuser
```

`showmount -e 192.168.1.33`:

```bsh
Export list for 192.168.1.33:
/i-data/5519db32/nfs              *
/i-data/5519db32/nfs/Hiddenslate1 (everyone)
/i-data/76a39839/nfs/Hiddenslate2 (everyone)
```

Comment: Does `showmount -e 192.168.1.33` help?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Just for sure...

Answer (score 0):

Check the [nas](https://support.zyxel.eu/hc/en-us/articles/360003647359-NAS-Series-Creating-a-NFS-share) first. Especially this :

```
DN/IP   Enter the domain name(s) or IP address(es) that can have access to the NFS share.
Enter "*" to make the share available to all users in the network. You can also enter a wildcard, such as "*.domain.com" to indicate that all users within that network have access to the share.
```

Comment: I set it as `*` as shown in the image in the question.

Comment: Just for sure... ls -la /media/NAS

Comment: Yup I did that. Nothing.

Comment: mkdir /media/NAS/volume1

Comment: I did that of course :)

Comment: Ok :). Just for sure, I said :D.

Comment: Does nothing, does nothing..... Check the mounts after that.